# Simple removeVowel function not changing input string

Tags: string, dart, debugging

I'm trying to make a simple function in dart to test on which should remove all vowels from an input string but its seems my code never changes the from the original input. Could anyone help me with this? thanks

```
  String removeVowel( str) {
  var toReturn = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    var temp = str.substring(i,i+1);

    if (temp != 'a' || temp != 'e' || temp != 'i' || temp != 'o' || temp!= 'u')
    {
      toReturn = toReturn + temp;
    }
  }
  return toReturn;
}
```

and what my tests shows:

```
00:02 +0 -1: dog --> dg [E]
  Expected: 'dg'
    Actual: 'dog'
     Which: is different.
            Expected: dg
              Actual: dog
                       ^
             Differ at offset 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good first try but there is a much easier way of doing this.
`replaceAll` should do the trick

```
String removeVolwels(String s){
  return s.replaceAll(RegExp('[aeiou]'),'');
}
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html

To make your code work you should change the `||` to `&&`

```
String removeVowel( str) {
  var toReturn = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    var temp = str.substring(i,i+1);

    if (temp != 'a' && temp != 'e' && temp != 'i' && temp != 'o' && temp!= 'u')
    {
      toReturn = toReturn + temp;
    }
  }
  return toReturn;
}
```